# String to HAML using Ruby and Regular Expression, creating newlines and tabs

Tags: ruby, regex, string, haml

I need to know the correct syntax for creating haml out of the following string:

`string = "%div.page-title//%h1//<title>/%small <subtitle>"`

It needs to find `/` & `//`, remembering the count for creating the indentation.

The above string needs to become:

```
%div.page-title
  %h1
    <title>
    %small <subtitle>
```

Between the `< >` is not html, but I'm going to replace these with other variables..

I did some researching and have seen that probably the `String.scan` method is useful, but I've been trying stuff for a couple of hours and I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a single nested set, meaning you don't go up a level, try the following

```
string = string = "%div.page-title//%h1//<title>/%small <subtitle>"
string.split('//').each_with_index do |string, index|
  string.split('/').each do |elem|
    row = ""
    index.times { row << "  " }
    row << elem
    puts row
  end
end
```

Comment: Code didn't work directly, the concept was good though, it was enough to get me in the right direction.. This is what worked for me: `string.split('//').collect.with_index { |string,index|
      string.split('/').collect { |elem| "#{"\t" * index}#{elem}" }
    }.join("\n")`..